# Executables not Working like Regular

Tags: command-line, bash

When I type this command

`nohup CloudCompute.command &`

it produces the result

`[1] 782`

which is what I want. (It's the PID number BTW)

So, when I run this same command in an executable (`.command`), and try to append the output to a file, it does not work. It just prints what `CloudCompute.command` outputs, not the actual PID which shows when you run it. I am sure it is in the same directory.

Why is this happening? What can I do to get the executable to produce the same output as manually typing it?

Thanks

Comment: And what does the executable `.command` do?

Comment: @muru That's just the file extension, not an executable. Sorry for the bad language.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening?

That output:

```
[1] 782
```

is not from the executable. That what `bash` writes to the terminal, when you execute someting in the backgroud. It's the job number `[1]` and the PID `782` of the process. Later when the process finished you will see something like:

```
[1]+  Done                    command
```

This is also from `bash` noticing that the process with job number 1 has finished.

When running a command in the background, the PID is stored in the variable `$!`:

```
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 1234
$ echo $!
1234
```

---

> What can I do to get the executable to produce the same output as manually typing it?

Therefore, your executable *is* producing the same output.

Comment: When I add `echo $! > test.txt` to the end of my executable, but `test.txt` contains nothing.

Comment: @APCoding you have to write that instantly after calling the command. Not in the end of the script.

Comment: I did. This is my entire script:

Comment: `cd CC \n
nohup ./CloudCompute.command \n
echo $! > test.txt`

Comment: And `CloudCompute.command` is just a simple `echo` test.